# Could not find or load main class - java - gradle -

Tags: java, gradle, jar, executable-jar

My project has the following structure:

- src
- - main/
- - - java/
- - - - io/
- - - - models/
- - - - services/
- - - - Application.java

This is how my gradle is configured to build the jar:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'Application'
        )
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

So, I'm execution the gradlew build task and when I execute the jar **I got the following error:**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Application
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, Intellij Idea, Java 8 and gradle 6.3

**What am I missing to put the jar running?**

Comment: I think you'll need `'Main-Class' : 'java.io.Application'`, though you may want a different package name and also consider the 'application' plugin for Gradle.

Comment: re: application plugin. This diff on GitHub illustrates the benefits/impact of using the plugin, as it previously used a style such as you are using - https://github.com/peidevs/WarO_Groovy/commit/4ad0b13fb6e08e0667e3d86c0aabbbdb4695e062#diff-49a96e7eea8a94af862798a45174e6ac43eb4f8b4bd40759b5da63ba31ec3ef7

Comment: Could you post the strcture of you jar file and the content of the MANIFEST.MF